# Wifi does not show any wifi networks or wlan0

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

Something strange happened, I was at the airport using my laptop fine.  I shut it down turned it on the next day at my destination and now it detects no wifi networks.

The laptop does not have a ethernet port so I can't run anything via the laptop.

I put on a USB stick the [wireless info script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) that I found on a debugging answer.  Here is the output [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cbfc188a1d6ba03909bf4198ea7b5e77) or a [paste.ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24277004/) as well as what i was allowed to past without going over char limit

EDIT:
output of `lspci -knn`

```
$ lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0a03] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller [8086:9c43] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:9c03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 8 Series Thermal [8086:9c24] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
```

Comment: If you paste at http://paste.ubuntu.com there is no char limit

Comment: @AndroidDev went ahead and added that link as well

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci -knn`? For some reason that section in the info script is blank.

Comment: @AndroidDev gone ahead and added that in

Comment: Hmmm... it looks like the kernel isn't even detecting the Wi-Fi card...

Comment: @AndroidDev I tried doing a ubuntu usb stick to boot, but it also showed no wifi's available when i did that.  Not sure why it would stop working? Maybe a update screwed everything? No way to fix?

Comment: Very strange. Well, if anyone can help you, it would be Chili555 or Pilot6.